# Insert new JS method from JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need call from JavaScript file php like example

```
$.post("my.php", 
           function(data)
       {
            data; // data is string "function Alert(){ alert("text"); };"
    }
);
```

so from php I get new JS function. Like example function Alert(){ alert("text"); };

Can I insert that functionality into loaded js file? And how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you *must* do this, I would advise against sending back all that text. Just send back the body:

```
alert("text");
```

Then you can do this:

```
$.post('my.php', function(data) {
  new Function(data) ();
});
```

By wrapping the code up in a function you (to some extent) contain the possible weirdness that might be caused by a simple "eval()".  (You could alternatively do "eval()" in its own anonymous function, but it's really hard for me to recommend using "eval()" at all on SO.)

Now, if you want to *keep* the function around for invocation later, then you'd do something like this:

```
$.post('my.php', function(data) {
  window['newFunction'] = new Function(data);
});
```

Then you can call it as `window.newFunction()` whenever you like.

Comment: Won't this just run the function right away?  I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: Well your guess is as good as mine :-)  The OP is pretty sparse.

Answer (score 0):

Try `eval`

```
$.post("my.php", function(data)
    {
        eval(data); // data is string "function Alert(){ alert("text"); };"
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the `eval` function, which evaluates a string as JS code:  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

(Be careful with it, as there are obvious security concerns.)

Answer (score 0):

Set `dataType` to script to tell jQuery to evaluate it.

> "script": Evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain text.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Use:

```
$.post("my.php", function(data){
}, 'script');
```

or:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'my.php',
  success: function(data){
  }
  dataType: 'script'
});
```

Does the request need to be a POST?  If not, you can use [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

```
$.getScript('my.php', function(data){
});
```

Which is the same as:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'my.php',
  success: function(data){
  }
  dataType: 'script'
});
```

This method uses jQuery's [`$.globalEval`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.globalEval/) instead of `eval()`.

Answer (score 0):

if you know you're getting a new function from the php, you should be able to just instantiate it when you get it back:

```
$.post("my.php", 
       function(data){
          data();
       }
);
```

I would avoid `eval` b/c of security issues.

Comment: You can't do that.  `data` is a string, and you can't use strings like that.

Comment: ok, not too familiar with php and ajax requests.  What about a JSONP solution?